# functions with types opaque to a library but specific to an application

Tags: haskell, types

I want to pass a function:

```
f :: a -> CmdRequest -> (a, CmdResponse)
```

from an application A to a system S.

S

- defines CmdRequest and CmdResponse
- at initialization: given/stores `f`
- at initialization: stores an initial value of `a` (as an opaque value, S cannot see any `a` structure)
- calls `f` (as part of system operation)
- passing it `a` values it previously stored (from previous calls or system initialization)
- stores the resulting first `a` component of the return type

A

- defines `f`
- at initialization: passes `f` to S
- at initialization: passes initial value of `a` to S
- can use specific types for `a` (e.g., Data.HashMap)
- when `f` is called it can see the internal structure (e.g., Data.HashMap) of `a`

How can this be done in Haskell/GHC?

**What would be the type signature of S's State?
I think it can be as simple as**

```
State a :: ...
```

**but is there a way to hide `a` ? (where "hide" means not specify a type parameter to `State`)**

I initially tried type-classes and existential types, but got stuck.

[example on github](https://github.com/haroldcarr/snippets/tree/master/storage-callbacks)

```
A                              S                   S's State
  initialization
.                              .                       .
.                              .                       .
.                              .                       .
|                              |                       |
x---------- pass f ----------->|                       |
|                              x----- store f -------->|
x--------------- a ----------->|                       |
|                              x----- store a -------->|
                               |                       |
                               .                       .
                               .                       .
                               .                       .
  system operation
                               |                       |
                               |                       |
                               x------- get f -------->|
                               |                       |
                               x------- get a -------->|
                               |                       |
|<---- call f a CmdRequest ----|                       |
|                              |                       |
|-- return (a', CmdResponse) ->|                       |
|                              |                       |
|                              x----- store a' ------->|
|                              |                       |
.                              .                       .
.                              .                       .
.                              .                       .
|<--- call f a' CmdRequest ----|                       |
|                              |                       |
|- return (a'', CmdResponse) ->|                       |
|                              |                       |
|                              x----- store a'' ------>|
|                              |                       |
.                              .                       .
.                              .                       .
.                              .                       .
```

Comment: Why does anything special need to be done? What's wrong with having L's API include functions like `fooWithCallback :: (a -> CmdRequest -> (a, CmdResponse)) -> {- type of foo actions -}`? The type of foo actions will have to have a parameter for `a`, but it really shouldn't require any tricks or hard work.

Comment: For an example of this kind of API, check out [`atomicModifyIORef`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-IORef.html#v:atomicModifyIORef). It has type `IORef a -> (a -> (a, b)) -> IO b`, which is essentially the same as the type `(a -> () -> (a, b)) -> IORef a -> IO b`; squinting at this you can see `()` as a sort of (especially boring) `CmdRequest`, `b` as a sort of `CmdResponse`, and `IORef a -> IO b` as the type of foo actions to make this fit the shape I proposed in my previous comment.

Comment: I can see no problem with this. Just keep in mind that if A defines `f` and `CmdRequest` is opaque, then `f` can act on its `CmdRequest` argument only using the functions exported by L.

Comment: There could be a real question here, depending on what is meant by L "storing `a`". Presumably it has to do so in a structure which is fed in to L by A, which could be parameterized on `a`, but what if the same structure needs to be used for varying types `a`? But the question as it stands is unanswerably broad, I think.

Comment: @ReidBarton Their is a storage structure, but A does not know about it. I added more info and a sequence diagram to the question to hopefully narrow it down.

Comment: @DanielWagner I was trying to make `a` "invisible" to the library but open to the application.  Perhaps it is a simple as adding an `a` type parameter to the declaration of storage.

Comment: Well, a library L cannot have "state" aside from what it is fed by the application A, unless you are using `unsafePerformIO` or something similar.

Comment: "functions with types opaque to a library but specific to an application". This is the essence of polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Having a function opaque to a library but specific to an application is Haskell's bread and butter. For instance, consider [Data.Map](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.9.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html%20Data.Map) from the "containers" package.

A map, `m :: Map k a`, is a piece of data which associates keys, `k`, to values `a`. The Data.Map library doesn't need to know the structure of its values, in fact, keeping the definition of `Map` polymorphic in `k` and `a` precludes the library from doing *anything* to the contents of the keys and values. Well, almost anything. Typeclases change the conversation a little, and if a user supplies a function on keys or values then they can be changed. The important point remains, however, the polymorphic parametricity restricts what can be done within the library.

You could try to rid yourself of that polymorphic parameter using ExistentialTypes. In terms of your GitHub Code, you could define state using something like:

```
{-# Language ExistentialQuantification #-}
import           Control.Concurrent.MVar

data State = forall a . State
  {
    _nextValue     :: MVar a
  , _applyLogEntry :: a -> CmdRequest -> (a, CmdResponse)
  }
```

Where I have removed the monad parameter from your `data State m a` for the sake of clarity. The value parameter, `a`, is now hidden by the existential quantification. Ever retrieving the stored value becomes a sticking point. The below code,

```
getStVal :: State -> IO a
getStVal st@(State mva f) = takeMVar mva
```

throws a compilation error, mentioning how the expected type of the function is `IO a` (due to the `getStVal` signature) but the actual type is `IO a1` (due to `State` type). This is because `getStVal` is asking for a specific (although unknown at compile time) type, whereas the data definition says the value could be any type (but that we can't assume any particular type at compile time.)

Passing the stored value of `a` to App doesn't help either, as there is no way for App to vary it's behavior depending on the value of a. The state value can be updated, but never directly inspected. (You can include typeclass information to signal that certain methods, e.g, show, can be applied to the type. [more info](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types))

There are other extensions which you could try. Ultimately, I'm not sure GADTs or RankNTypes will fare any better. You will have to convince the compiler--somehow--that your programs will be able to use the unknown type. But really, polymorphic parameters are usually the best way to do this.

Comment: You are right that what I was calling L is not really a library.  But it is not a client/server either. For now I just changed (above) what I was calling L/Libary to S/System.  So S is an independent running system that is given callbacks.  You are also right that this is simple parametric polymorphism - just adding a type parameter to S solves the "problem".  I have added a link to such a parametric solution.  My real question (which admittedly I did not formulate too well) was if there was a way to do this without a type parameter (see my edited/updated question).

Comment: FWIW: I do use the haskell binding to ZeroMQ

Comment: @haroldcarr, I updated the answer based on updated question. I hope it helps. It is a broad question, so I'm not sure how to address it. I have played with the language extensions a bit. Usually it is interesting, but rarely have I actually opted to use them.